# Zend_Application issue with extending Frontcontroller and using extended Frontcontroller application resource

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller, zend-application

I extended the Zend Frontcontroller with a personal one and also extended the frontcontroller application resource to use my personal front controller. All it basically does for the moment is assign the front variable within the application resource method `getFrontController` to my personal front controller. Lastly, I added the pluginpaths variable within `application.ini` to use my personal Application Resources. In any case, I'm getting the `Zend Frontcontroller` returned to me instead of my personal one. Anybody know why my personal application frontcontroller resource
isnt being used?
    `

Comment: I'm interested in do this in my app.  Is there any chance you would be will to post how you did it after you get it working or just the source code so I can look at it?

Comment: Frontcontroller resource - http://pastebin.com/H9hvVCKz

Comment: Application ini setting - http://pastebin.com/kaYPs0S1

Comment: Frontcontroller class - http://pastebin.com/GqAjLGna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `Zend_Controller_Front` is a singleton, you will also need to override the getInstance() method to ensure it creates an instance of your class instead of the base class. You can just cut and paste the method to do this:

```
public static function getInstance()
{
    if (null === self::$_instance) {
        self::$_instance = new self();
    }

    return self::$_instance;
}
```

Comment: I had the static variable $_instance on my personal frontcontroller, and this seemed to be the issue.